# RavenDb client issue with NewtonJson.NET version 4.0.8.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ravendb, json.net

I have a problem with RavenDb client and NewtonJson.NET in integration test project.
I am receiving following exception :

> Assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' which has a higher version than
>   referenced assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.8.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'  ...\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll

I need to use System.Net.Http.Formatting which uses NewtonSoft.Json 4.5.0.0
and RavenDb client which uses 4.0.8.0.
**I do not want to use unstable builds of RavenDb** because this code needs to go in production fast.
Do you have some solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RavenDB 1.0.972 (stable), which depends on NewtonSoft.Json 4.5.7.  You can find it on NuGet.

https://nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Client/1.0.972