# Nuget dependency error installing RavenDb Client

Tags: dependencies, ravendb, nuget

So I'm trying to install RavenDB.Client into a fresh Asp.Net Mvc 4.0 project and getting the following error.

```
PM> Install-Package RavenDB.Client -Version 1.0.980
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (= 4.0.8)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NLog (= 2.0.0.2000)'.
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.8'.
Successfully installed 'NLog 2.0.0.2000'.
You are downloading RavenDB.Client from Hibernating Rhinos, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.ravendb.net/licensing. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'RavenDB.Client 1.0.980'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Updating 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.6' to 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.8' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' that is compatible with 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.8'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package RavenDB.Client -Version 1.0.980
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Unfortunately, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client is one of the litany of things that is installed by default that I actually do need to use. What are my options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been asked [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970591/can-i-install-ravendb-client-alongside-microsoft-aspnet-webapi-client) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212303/asp-net-web-api-and-ravendb-compatibility) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795378/ravendb-client-issue-with-newtonjson-net-version-4-0-8-0).

The best advice as of today is to use the pre-release "unstable" build of RavenDB.  The 2.0 release is nearing RTM, and the unstable builds are pretty good.